# MSMQ Remote Private: UnsupportedFormatNameOperation after one use

Tags: c#, msmq

I am new to MSMQ and suspect I either have my queues configured wrong or programmatically (is that a word?)causing them to get hung up.

When everything starts I can send one message and that works wonderfully. I can see (ie via mmc on that machine) the message in the remote machine queue. I then go to access it and I get my UnsupportedFormatNameOperation error. If I try to send another message I get the same error in the send method that just worked a few seconds earlier.

What is even more frustrating is that my catch is **NOT** picking up the exception so I was unaware and looking elsewhere (read wasting time) till I explored the queue object in the debugger.

Now if I reset the Message Service on remote I lose my message in the queue and still get the same error. If I reboot same result.

On local (dev machine) if I reset the Message Service I still get the error. If I reboot something gets recycled and I can send exactly one message again.

Further after reboot of dev machine and exploring the queue object on the first run I find that I am getting the error the **FIRST** time around but it still sends the message.

So I am clearly doing something wrong but clueless as to what.

Here is my send code:

```
private void SendLoginMessage(...bunch of parms)
        {
            //hardcoded path? yup!!
            MessageQueue msmq = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:W2K8R2_SQL2K8R2\private$\best_simulator");

            try
            {
                LoginStatusMessage LgnMsg = new LoginStatusMessage()
                {
                    ...assign parms to my 
                };
                msmq.Send(LgnMsg);
            }
            catch (MessageQueueException msmqex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msmqex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                msmq.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The description for [UnsupportedFormatNameOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeueerrorcode%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is

> The requested operation for the specified format name is not supported.
>
> Message Queuing returns this error when the requested operation is not supported for the specified format name. Operations include trying to open a queue to receive messages by specifying a direct format name.

So I guess your problem may be at your receive code.